# How can display the total amount of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use rails 5.1.6 I use gem kaminari and api-pagination for pagination.

How to find the total count of the posts from the pagination.
Since per_page gives 10 from the first page, and not the total number.

How to get the total count of the posts even after pagination

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def post
    posts = paginate Post.all, per_page: 10
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate(posts.as_json)
  end

  def index
    post
  end

end
```

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more. Provide some context.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I updated the question

Comment: Where you want to get the count? What's the purpose?

Comment: You should not name controller action with name `post`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've pasted, I'm assuming you will be sending `page` value too as part of `params` and you want the total Posts count as well.

If that is the case, you can write your code as follows:

```
response = {
  posts_count: Post.count,
  posts: Post.page(params[:page).per(10)
}
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(response.as_json)
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the total count of the posts regardless of the pagination, you can use:

```
Post.count
```

as per: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count

Your code might look something like:

```
response = {
  count: Post.count,
  posts: paginate Post.all, per_page: 10
}
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(response.as_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save all posts to a variable:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def post
    all_posts = Post.all
    posts = paginate all_posts, per_page: 10
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate(posts.as_json)
  end
end
```

Now you can use `all_posts.size` to get all posts count.